Convergence of weighted averages for functions
I have a distribution over $1/n, 2/n, \dots, n/n$ with weights $\frac{1}{n}$ in each point, on the other hand I have distribution on the same set with weights $p_{n,1}, \dots, p_{n,n}$ (for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$). I am wondering when for a function $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ the following will be true:
$$\left| \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac{1}{n} f(i/n) - \sum^n_{i = 1} p_{n,i} f(i/n) \right| \to 0, \quad n \to \infty.$$
Moreover, I know that $\mathbb{E}_{u \sim Uniform(0, 1)}f(u) < \infty$.
I am interested in the conditions under which this will be true. I have in mind this one:
$$ \sum^n_{i = 1} \left| \frac{1}{n} - p_{n,i} \right| \to 0,$$
However, I am not sure how to prove it formally.

Isn't $ \sum^n_{i = 1} \left( \frac{1}{n} - p_i \right)=1-1=0$ for all $n$? Your limit relation holds only when $p_i=\frac 1 n$ for each $i$.

@geetha290krm, you're right. I should've put |.| into the sum. Thank you.

Your sum is at least $|1/n-p_i|$ so you will need $p_i=0$ for every $i$. In other wrods, your condition never holds!

You actually want $p_{i,n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, right?

@user469053, very correct remark, indeed I want this

@geetha290krm, you're right, I edited the setting, so that it reflects that for each $n$ could I have a different list of $p_{n,i}$

I think the result holds in the new version only for bounded $f$. Finite expectation w.r.t. uniform distribution  is not enough.
